# How to restrict file access based on file path under private directory?

Tags: 7, files

I have a list of files under  `sites/default/files/private/abcde/manuals/`.

I want to add restriction to the files based on certain logic which I can add in the code in a hook.
The logic would be based on a parameter set in by the admin.
So if the value  set to allow in the admin settings form , I would like to give access to view or download files under `'sites/default/files/private/abcde/manuals/'` else would like to prevent user from accessing it.

Answer (score 1):

Requests to files in the private file directory are routed through Drupal and access logic for these requests can be added by implementing [hook_file_download](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_file_download/7.x).
The only argument to that hook implementation is `$uri`, which is the URI to the file. Using string comparison to see if you want to act upon this request should get you what you need.

Quoting the docs:

> If the user does not have permission to access the file, return -1. If the user has permission, return an array with the appropriate headers. If the file is not controlled by the current module, the return value should be NULL.